# Numpy ndarray ValueError, dimensions don't match

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am having a Problem with the `np.append` and `np.vstack`

I am trying to combine a 48x48 grayscale face image with an array of the landmarks from the face.

So I can have an Array with the images and the corresponding landmarks to give to am ML model for training.

```
landmarks_train = []
X_train_with_landmarks = []

all_landmarks = np.empty((0, 478, 3))

for i in range(len(X_train)):
    
    image = X_train[i]
    
    image = image.astype(np.uint8)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    landmarks = get_landmarks(image)
        
    if len(landmarks) == 478:
        # only save them and the image if all 478 are found
        
        landmarks = np.array(landmarks)
        
        print(landmarks.shape) # -> result is (478,3)
        print(X_train[i].shape) # -> result (48, 48, 1)
        
        all_landmarks = np.vstack((all_landmarks, landmarks))
 
        X_train_with_landmarks.append(np.concatenate((X_train[i], landmarks), axis=-1))

X_train_with_landmarks = np.array(X_train_with_landmark
```

In the get_landmarks() method, it gets the landmarks with the MediaPipe Face mesh:

```
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
face_mesh = mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(max_num_faces=1, refine_landmarks=True)

# convert to RGB so that MediaPipe can work with it and then back
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
results_face_mesh = face_mesh.process(image)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

if results_face_mesh.multi_face_landmarks:

   for facial_landmarks in results_face_mesh.multi_face_landmarks:

     facial_landmarks_res = []
     for landmark in facial_landmarks.landmark:
        x, y, z = landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z
        facial_landmarks_res.append([x, y, z])

     return facial_landmarks_res
```

I then get an ValueError that says the dimensions are not the same when I do the operations:

```
all_landmarks = np.vstack((all_landmarks, landmarks))
```

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)

And when I remove the `np.vstack` line, I also get the same Error as above, for this one:

```
X_train_with_landmarks.append(np.concatenate((X_train[i], landmarks), axis=-1))
```

I am now not sure what is wrong and can't find any solution to fix this.
Maybe someone can help.

PS: Perhaps this is also helpful. How I build X_train, the images are from the fer2013 dataset and are loaded into a pandas DataFrama df.

```
train_set = df[df['Usage'] == 'Training']
X_train = np.array([np.fromstring(image, dtype=int, sep=' ') for image in train_set['pixels']])
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 48, 48, 1).astype('float32')
```

I tried several operations to expand those array like the following but nothing worked.

```
expanded_X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train[i], axis=0)
        X_train_with_landmarks.append(np.concatenate((expanded_X_train, landmarks), axis=-1))
```

Comment: So did you check the dimensions of `all_landmarks`, `landmarks`?  Do you understand those dimensions?

Comment: `all_landmarks` has the dimension (0, 478, 3) and `landmarks` (478,3) and for my understanding they would fit into the `all_landmarks` array because the “first” dimension would then say how many landmarks are in the array.

Comment: Reread `vstack`.  Also repeated `vstack` (or other versions of concatenate) in loop is inefficient.

Comment: Thank you, I now saw the error with the `vstack` and changed it to be `all_landmarks = landmarks` in the first loop and then `all_landmarks = np.vstack((all_landmarks, landmarks))`

But the Value error with the `np.concatenate` still exists. How could I fix it, or do you recommend another strategie in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `np.concatenate()` is not what you need in this case because you are tying to concatenate 1-channel `image` 48x48x1 (or 3-channel 48x48x3 if not grayscale) and list of 3D coordinates 478x3. Even if you expand dimensions of `landmarks` and get 1x478x3, concatenation will not be possible because all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis (which is -1) must match exactly.

If you need to store `image` and `landmarks` data in one array, I can suggest to create 2-channel image with shape 48x48x2 (or 4-channel 48x48x4 if not grayscale), where first channel will be `image` and second channel will be 48x48 matrix with z-coords as values and some `base_number` for all coords, that are not in `landmarks`. Pay attention, that I proceed from the assumption that first two `landmarks` coords (x and y) are between 0 and 48 and z-coords may be anything.

```
base_number = 0 # or any other
matrix = np.ones((X_train[0].shape[0], X_train[0].shape[1], 1)) * base_number
matrix[landmarks[:, 0].astype(int), landmarks[:, 1].astype(int), 0] = landmarks[:, 2]
result = np.dstack((X_train[0], matrix)) # [48, 48, 2] or [48, 48, 4]
X_train_with_landmarks.append(result)
```